# Django __str__ returned non-string (type tuple), i didn't define __str__

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a duplicate reporting system on Django, and i created a table on my models.py that goes

```
class DupReport(models.Model):
count = models.IntegerField()
oldersub = models.ForeignKey('Submission', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='older_sub')
newersub = models.ForeignKey('Submission', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='newer_sub')
```

And when i go to admin to add a row, the menu that displays the rows works fine, but when i click add DupReport, i get this:

> TypeError at /admin/apppickoff/dupreport/add/
>
> **str** returned non-string (type tuple)
>
> < a href="{% add_preserved_filters history_url %}" class="historylink">{% trans "History" %}< /a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a stray comma at the end of any `__str__` definitions that you did write.

Returning a value with a comma at the end will turn your value into a tuple containing that value.

Comment: oh thanks that worked, though i removed a comma from another table's __str__, and that table was working just fine

Comment: @ViniciusVaghetti That's probably because the admin view of a table doesn't call `__str__()` of the model. But `__str__()` is called for target models of foreign keys.

Comment: oh it makes sense, it was the submission model, which was to be displayed when i was to add a new DupReport and would read it's __str__